# using php printout in another php file

Tags: php, sql

okay I am trying to learn here I am a noob, basically, this is my current (**server.php**) code,

```
<?php
/**
 * Sample php server script for a wookmark integration
 *
 * @author Sebastian Helzle <sebastian@helzle.net>
 */

/**
 * Basic class which provides all functions to retrieve and paginate pictures
 */
class PictureDatabase {

  /**
   * @var array $data
   */
  protected $data;

  /**
   * @var int $itemsPerPage
   */
  protected $itemsPerPage;

  function __construct($data, $itemsPerPage) {
    $this->data = $data;
    $this->itemsPerPage = $itemsPerPage;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the pictures of the given page or an empty array if page doesn't exist
   * @param int $page
   * @return array
   */
  public function getPage($page=1) {
    if ($page > 0 && $page <= $this->getNumberOfPages()) {
      $startOffset = ($page - 1) * $this->itemsPerPage;
      return array_slice($this->data, $startOffset, $this->itemsPerPage);
    }
    return array();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the maximum number of pages
   * @return int
   */
  public function getNumberOfPages() {
    return ceil(count($this->data) / $this->itemsPerPage);
  }
}

// Our data source
$data = include ('xyz.php');





// Make data array a bit bigger to have more pages
for ($i=0; $i<3; $i++) {
  $data = array_merge($data, $data);
}

// Create instance of picture database with 10 items per page and our data as source
$pictureDatabase = new PictureDatabase($data, 10);

$result = array(
  'success' => TRUE,
  'message' => 'Retrieved pictures',
  'data' => array()
);

$callback = isset($_REQUEST['callback']) ? $_REQUEST['callback'] : false;

// Get requested page number from request and return error message if parameter is not a number
$page = 1;
try {
  $page = intval($_REQUEST['page']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
  $result['success'] = FALSE;
  $result['message'] = 'Parameter page is not a number';
}

// Get data from database
$result['data'] = $pictureDatabase->getPage($page);

if (count($result['data']) == 0 || $page >= $pictureDatabase->getNumberOfPages()) {
  $result['success'] = TRUE;
  $result['message'] = 'No more pictures';
}

// Encode data as json or jsonp and return it
if ($callback) {
  header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
  echo $callback.'('.json_encode($result).')';
} else {
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($result);
}
```

okay now under //datasource, the original is

```
$data = array (
array (
'id' => "1",
'title' => "First image",
'url' => "http://www.example.org/1",
'width' => "200",
'height' => "283",
'image' => "/images/image_1_big.jpg",
'preview' => "/images/image_1.jpg"
),
array (
'id' => "2",
'title' => "Second image",
'url' => "http://www.example.org/2",
'width' => "200",
'height' => "300",
'image' => "/images/image_2_big.jpg",
'preview' => "/images/image_2.jpg"
)
);
```

now what I have done with the help of few people here is gotten another (**xyz.php**) file to print out this from sql,

```
<?php
// Our data source
$conn = mysql_connect("", "", "");

if (!$conn) {
    echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("")) {
    echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
//= Query ========================//
$sql = mysql_query("select id, title, url, width, height, image, preview from mmf_content");

//= Closed while ====================//
/*everytime it fetches the row, adds it to array...*/
$foo = "array (\n";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $foo.= "array (\n";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        $foo .= "'{$key}' => \"{$value}\",\n";
    }
    $foo = substr($foo,0,strlen($foo)-2)."\n";//removes the comma at the end
    $foo .="),\n";
}
$foo = substr($foo,0,strlen($foo)-2)."\n";//removes the comma at the end
$foo .= ');';
echo '<pre>'.$foo.'</pre>';
?>
```

this is the printout,

```
array (
array (
'id' => "1",
'title' => "First image",
'url' => "http://www.example.org/1",
'width' => "200",
'height' => "283",
'image' => "/images/image_1_big.jpg",
'preview' => "/images/image_1.jpg"
),
array (
'id' => "2",
'title' => "Second image",
'url' => "http://www.example.org/2",
'width' => "200",
'height' => "300",
'image' => "/images/image_2_big.jpg",
'preview' => "/images/image_2.jpg"
)
);
```

now currently if in the server.php

```
// Our data source
$data = include ('xyz.php');
```

it doesnt work, but if i manually put the printout it works perfectly.

so how do i make $data = to printout of xyz.php

Comment: Important Side note: don't use `mysql_` function it is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, by the time you become a nice programmer it will most probably be removed. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used.

Comment: instead of `echo '<pre>'.$foo.'</pre>';` you should do `return '<pre>'.$foo.'</pre>';`

Comment: so basically you saying i should replace all the mysql_ with pdo_mysql_?

Comment: if you just want to return array no need to convert it in the string as you are doing in the **XYZ.PHP**

Comment: @DharmeshPatel so if i keep everything the same and change echo to return it will work?

Comment: I tried using return both in the xyz.php and the server.php and still does not output the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include xyz.php you will have access to everything inside so no need to return anything. Just put this inside xyz.php:

```
$data = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $data[]= $row;
}
```

Then inside server.php you will be able to access $data.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
$foo = "array (\n";
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $foo.= "array (\n";
    foreach ($row as $key => $value){
        $foo .= "'{$key}' => \"{$value}\",\n";
    }
    $foo = substr($foo,0,strlen($foo)-2)."\n";//removes the comma at the end
    $foo .="),\n";
}
$foo = substr($foo,0,strlen($foo)-2)."\n";//removes the comma at the end
$foo .= ');';
echo '<pre>'.$foo.'</pre>';
```

to

```
$foo = array();
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
    $foo[]= $row;
}
return $foo;
```